# EMF does not generate list with type

Tags: eclipse, emf, ecore

I am trying to create an ecore file that represents my model.

I run into problems however, because when I generate the model,
the java files contain

```
EList getFunctions();
```

instead of

```
EList<Function> getFunctions();
```

Where can I choose that EMF adds the types to the lists?

EDIT:
I did specify the attribute. Here's a screenshot of my configuration:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/RE9drmO.png (sorry for the link, don't have enough reputation to post directly)]

Here's the interface that is generated for FunctionCall (I removed the auto-generated comments):

```
import org.eclipse.emf.common.util.EList;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject;

public interface FunctionCall extends EObject {

    Function getSource();
    void setSource(Function value);

    Function getTarget();
    void setTarget(Function value);

    DependencyGraph getDg();
    void setDg(DependencyGraph value);

    EList getBendpoints();

} // FunctionCall
```

---

Problem "solved":

After a long playing around and no success, I've re-installed Eclipse (and also completely wiped my settings & project settings).  I've re-imported my project and it seems to work now. 
I don't know why, though...

Comment: Any solution here? I got the same Problem

Comment: Check your '.genmodel' file configuration, perhaps you let the java-1.5 compatibility?

Comment: Hi, it turned out that my Eclipse installation was completely messed up and after completely re-installing (incl. new download) it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the type in EType property. For specifying the attribute as an EList, you need to set the upper bound as -1.

Comment: @S.K Could you be more specific about the problem? Could you please share the java file which is getting generated out of FunctionCall class?

Comment: The problem is also visible here: 
[link](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.emf.doc%2Freferences%2Foverview%2FEMF.html&anchor=generation)

If you scroll to **Multiplicity-many references** you can see that the method _getBooks()_ returns an `EList` rather than an `EList<Book>`.

Does this example make it more understandable?

Comment: Can u try creating a new Child of EReference instead of EAttribute and let me know?

Comment: I did already in another entity. It is the same behaviour... :/

Comment: Can u also attach the FunctionlCall impl class also?

Comment: I dont think u can add a reference of an object which is not an EObject. org.eclipse.draw2d.geometry.Point is not an EObject. So how did u add that? Doesn't the genmodel file before generating the class from ecore throw any errors?

Comment: I created a plugin dependency on `org.eclipse.draw2d` (GEF) and then defined it as an `EData Type`. The documentation says it works like that. And I don't have any problems with the reference.
In DependencyGraph I have two lists for `Function`s and `FunctionCall`s (both EObject) and they show the same behaviour.